# Generating mip levels for a 2D texture array

Tags: opengl, textures

I've got a simple (I think) question about OpenGL texture arrays. I create my texture array with something like the following:

```
glTexImage3D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
        0,
        formatGL,
        width,
        height,
        slices,
        0,
        GL_RGBA, 
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
        nullptr);
```

Note that I don't want to actually load any images into it yet. I'm just creating the structure that I'll be filling with data later on.

So my questions are:

1. How do I generate the mip chain for each "slice" of the texture array? I don't want to physically generate the mip, I just want to complete the texture by telling it about the mip. I can do this with 2D textures simply by calling the glTexImage2D function with the mip level, size and also passing in a nullptr. I can't see how to do this with the glTexImage3D function given there's no "slice" parameter. The OpenGL superbible example only loads a .bmp into the first mip level for each texture in the array. Is it correct to say that using glTexSubImage3D, passing in a nullptr, will create the mip level I want for a given texture in the array?
2. Documentation at khronos.org on glGenerateMipMap specifies GL_TEXTURE_2D or GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP only. So is it correct to say I can't use this method for 2D texture arrays?

Here's what I do with 2D textures to create the mip chain:

```
    size_t i = 0, mipSizeX = width, mipSizeY = height;

    while(mipSizeX >= 1 || mipSizeY >= 1)
    {
        // Generate image for this mip level

        glTexImage2D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                        i,
                        formatGL,
                        mipSizeX,
                        mipSizeY,
                        0,
                        GL_RGBA, 
                        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                        nullptr);

        // Go to the next mip size.

        mipSizeX >>= 1;
        mipSizeY >>= 1;

        // and the next mipmap level.

        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can do this with 2D textures simply by calling the glTexImage2D function with the mip level, size and also passing in a nullptr. I can't see how to do this with the glTexImage3D function given there's no "slice" parameter.

Why not? glTexImage3D takes a mipmap level, just like glTexImage2D. It takes a size, which in 2D is two dimensions, but in 3D is three dimensions.

Indeed, the *only* difference between the two functions is the number of dimensions that they take (and therefore the possible `target` parameters). And there is a "slice" parameter; you used it with glTexImage3D in the call you showed us. There, it's called `depth`.

The difference between 3D textures and 2D array textures is that the `depth` does not change in lower mipmaps for 2D arrays. Each mipmap of the array has the same number of "slices" as every other mipmap.

> Documentation at khronos.org

If it's at "khronos.org" and not "opengl.org", then it's almost certainly talking about OpenGL **ES**, which does not have array textures (**later note:** ES 3.0 added array textures).

---

I honestly don't know how to be any clearer without actually writing your code for you.

```
size_t i = 0, mipSizeX = width, mipSizeY = height;

while(mipSizeX >= 1 || mipSizeY >= 1)
{
    // Generate image for this mip level

    glTexImage3D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                    i,
                    formatGL,
                    mipSizeX,
                    mipSizeY,
                    arrayCount,
                    0,
                    GL_RGBA, 
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                    nullptr);

    // Go to the next mip size.

    mipSizeX >>= 1;
    mipSizeY >>= 1;

    // and the next mipmap level.

    i++;
}
```

Also, you need to check that the mipmap sizes have a minimum value of 1. Because `(1 >> 1) == 0`.

Comment: I'm not sure what to put into the "slices" parameter in this scenario.    Zero?  The problem here is the fact I'm building a 2d texture, through the 3d interface doesn't really compute with my brain :p.

Comment: @Robinson: The problem is that you're not making a 2D texture. You're making an _array_ of 2D textures. The number of elements in that array is the _depth_ (I don't know where you got "slices" from, since [the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage3D.xml) clearly uses the word "depth".

Comment: Sorry, slices was how it was referred to somewhere else!  So I iterate the mip level *and also* iterate "depth", calling glTextImage3D, and GL will automatically expand the array as depth increments?  I assumed depth was "how many images I want in the array", rather than "index into an array", mostly because when I first call it the array doesn't yet exist.

Comment: @Robinson: Depth **is** "how many images I want in the array"; that's what I said when I wrote, "The number of elements in that array is the _depth_".

Comment: @Robinson: Think of it like allocating an array of objects with `new[]`. The `depth` is what you put in the []'s.

Comment: Yes nicol, but then how do I generate a mip map for a given mip level?  What do I put into depth then?  Sorry if I'm a little slow today.....

Comment: @Robinson: I said it in my answer: "The difference between 3D textures and 2D array textures is that _the depth does not change in lower mipmaps for 2D arrays_. Each mipmap of the array has the same number of "slices" as every other mipmap."

Comment: It's probably better if I illustrate the example with an edit to the question.  I've added what I'm doing at the moment to generate a 2D mip chain (maybe this is wrong too - but I seem to end up with a complete texture available for use!)

Comment: You've got "arraycount" for depth.  Is this arraycount the number of textures in the array?  If so that was the conceptual error I was making.  The call generates one mip level for *all* textures in the array in one shot, rather than individually having to do so for each individual "slice" in the array?  Otherwise the "depth" parameter has one meaning when you use it with level 0, and another meaning when you use it with level 1.

Comment: Ok, guess I'm going to wrap this one up, even though I still don't get it. :p.  I will use the "monkey-typewriter method", and fiddle about until it works.